# How to print specific output based on condition from name variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a dataframe `data` like that :

[image: data]

ANd I would like an output like that :

- name1

  sentences1

  sentences2

  sentences3
- name2

  sentences4
- name3

  sentences5

  sentences6

Here's what I did so far :

```
first = True

for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    if data['Name'][i+1] == data['Name'][i] :
        if first:
            first = False
            print(data['Name'][i])
            print()
            print(data['Sentences'][i])
        else:
            print()
            print(data['Sentences'][i])
           
    if data['Name'][i] != data['Name'][i+1] :
        print(data['Name'][i])
        print(data['Sentences'][i])
       
    else :
        print()
```

But that doesn't give me the right output, the name aren't print at the place I wanted. I think I misplace or forget something in my loop but what ?

Thanks

EDIT : I think I figured it out ! I would like to know if I'm right, that's what I change in my code :

```
first = True

for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    if data['Name'][i+1] == data['Name'][i] :
        if first:
            first = False
            print(data['Name'][i])
            print()
            print(data['Sentences'][i])
        else:
            print()
            print(data['Sentences'][i])
           
    if data['Name'][i] != data['Name'][i+1] :
        print(data['Name'][i+1]) #i+1 instead of i
        print(data['Sentences'][i+1])# i+1 instead of i
       
    else :
        print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a much cleaner way of doing it.

#### Note:

My DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

#### Code

```
for name in df.name.unique():
    print(name + ':\n')
    for index, value in df.sentences[df.name == name].items():
        print(value)
    print('\n')
```

#### Output

```
name1:

sentence1
sentence2
sentence3


name2:

sentence4


name3:

sentence5
sentence6
```

Try to modify the code above to your needs and see if it helps.

Comment: The name is at the end, not at the beginning. Furthermore, the syntax  (Name: sentences, dtype: object) is useless, I cannot have that in output. But otherwise, it's great !

Comment: I've edited the answer to (try to) better fit your needs.

Comment: That's wonderful, suo much less code than mine ! Congratulations, you're awesome :) Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to also **accept** the answer to that people can see it has a solution.

Comment: I need two statement and I'm stuck, I repost another question if you want to help again : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958966/how-to-print-specific-output-based-on-condition-from-two-variables