# How to print specific output based on condition from two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a dataframe like that :

[image: sentences]

And I would like an output like that :

**name1 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

*mission2 :*

sentences3

**name2 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences4

**name3 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences6

Here's what I did so far :

```
for name in df.Name.unique():
    print(name + ' :\n')
    for mission in df.Mission.unique():
        print(mission + ' :\n')
        for index, value in df.Phrases[df.Mission == mission].items():
            print(value)
            print()
    for index, value in df.Phrases[df.Name == name].items():
        print(value)
        print()
       
    print('\n')
```

But the output is not quite what I obtained and I see what is wrong but I cannot figure it out how to deal with it :

**name1 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

sentences4

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences3

sentences6

sentences1

sentences2

sentences3

**name2 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

sentences4

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences3

sentences6

sentences4

**name3 :**

*mission1 :*

sentences1

sentences2

sentences4

sentences5

*mission2 :*

sentences3

sentences6

sentences5

sentences6

Comment: you fail to check in the inner loops that name is same for that misson and so on..

Comment: Ooh I see, do you think you could provide me a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize the code for your own dataframe but the logic is the same:

#### My DataFrame:

[image]

#### Code

```
for name in df.name.unique():
    print(name)
    for miss in df.mission.unique():
        print('  ' + miss)
        for sentence in df.sentences[(df.name == name) & (df.mission == miss)].tolist():
            print('    ' + sentence)
```

#### Output

```
name1
  mission1
    sentence1
    sentence2
  mission2
    sentence3
name2
  mission1
    sentence4
  mission2
name3
  mission1
    sentence5
  mission2
    sentence6
```

Comment: Hello :) Just one more question : I use your code with my entire database. It works perfectly, except for one thing. It print the mission, even when there is no sentences affiliate with her. Do you have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask a new question and show with code and data what the problem is and what you want to achieve as well as what have you tried to far to do that (this way other people can be notified of a new question :] )